# Spring - Why is my select not validating correctly?

Tags: java, html, regex, spring, constraints

I have 2 `select` for selecting which country and port to ship an object to. My select code is like this:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="coffee-span-4">
            <label class="label label-shipto">* Shipping To:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="coffee-span-3">
            <label class="label label-ship">Country</label>
            <sf:select class="select drop-down-2" path="ship2country" id="country" onchange="enablePort(this.value)">
                <sf:option value="Select a Country" label="Select a Country"/>
                <sf:option value="0" label="USA"/>
                <sf:option value="1" label="China"/>
                <sf:option value="2" label="Germany"/>
            </sf:select>
            <sf:errors path="ship2country" cssClass="rfqerror"></sf:errors>
          </div>
          <div class="coffee-span-3">
            <label class="label label-ship">City / Port</label>
            <sf:select class="select drop-down-2" path="ship2port" id="cityport">
                <sf:option class="-----" value="-----" label="-----"/>
            </sf:select>
            <sf:errors path="ship2port" cssClass="rfqerror"></sf:errors>
          </div>
          <div class="coffee-span-2">

          </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the form, according to my .java bean file, the `<sf:errors>` should be triggered (`sf` is `<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`):

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]+$", message="You must select a country to ship to!")
private String ship2country;

@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]+$", message="You must select a port to ship to!")
private String ship2port;
```

I thought of using the `@Pattern` constraint with a regexp to validate it. But when I submit my form, only one of them shows up. Why is my other one not validating?

[image]

Comment: Don't know, but drop the `value="Select a Country"`. Let it submit an empty value, i.e. the lack of a value, i.e. the user didn't make a selection. Same for second `<select>`.

Comment: Don't know the rest of your setup, but maybe it's configured to stop on first `@Pattern` error. To verify, do you get the second error if you solve the first one?